# Lenovo X1 5th gen - Fan issues

Tags: lubuntu, lenovo, fan, overheating, fedora

Recently I have experienced fan issues with my Lenovo X1 (5th gen). In particular, when the machine is required to perform some longwinded intensive tasks that require the use of all computational resources, the fan works at 4000-5000 rpm, as I would expect, for less than 5 minutes, then drops to 2000-2500 rpm. I also found out that cpu frequency at the beginning of the tasks is about 2300/2400 MHz, then it drops to 1800/1900 MHz. This is odd not only because the machine seems to go into a sort of "survival mode", but also because cpu temperature is about 95-100 C.
I tried to use thinkfan, thinkfan-ui, but none of them works, and the issue described above is present on all distributions I have tried so far: ubuntu and lubuntu 22.04 as well as Fedora 25 (I tried an updated distro hoping that the issue could be ascribed to  some bug in newer kernels).

As per the configuration of thinkfan, I have followed the steps outlined here

https://gist.github.com/abn/de81ba413f860b00c2db3ee4aa83e035

Do you have any advice? Thanks

Comment: [Fedora 25 reached EOL in 2017](https://fedoramagazine.org/fedora-25-end-life/) & is off-topic here. Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and *official* flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site.  Ubuntu/Lubuntu use the same Ubuntu base so expecting a different result confuses me (*they used the same kernel, only UI differs*).

Comment: I was not expecting help on the Fedora side. I reported that the issue is also present on Fedora because I think it could be useful to track down the problem.

Comment: Do you see the same issue running Windows 11 (with latest drivers)? It might be that this is normal for your laptop, given the CPU temperature seems to be nearing its maximum...

Comment: Unable to answer your question as I was unable to run the script on Windows 10 (it is an R script that invokes parallelization and for the particular function used in R - mclapply - Windows does not allow to use more than one core)

Comment: You could take a look in the UEFI settings if there is an option to run the fans in performance mode or something like that.

Comment: You could run any sort of stress test in Windows.  If the CPU temp hits 100C there, then it's likely hardware related, loose heat sync or improperly applied thermal paste.